# Setting up html dropdown control's value using jquery in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In one of my .cshtml pages I have the following code:

```
<section>
        <label class="select">
            @if (itm.OutOfStock)
            {
                <select class="form-control" id="itm_SelectedQty" name="itm.SelectedQty" disabled="disabled">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => itm.SelectedQty, itm.QtyChoices, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            }
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => itm.MenuItemId, new { @class = "itm_MenuItemId" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => itm.ItemAmount, new { @class = "itm_ItemAmount" })
            <i></i>
        </label>
    </section>
```

and in Jquery, I have the following code:

```
                  $.each($(".table"), function (i, obj) {
                        $("select > option:selected", this).map(function (n, i) {
                            if($(i)[0].value == "1")
                            {
                                $(i)[0].val("0");
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

I am able to get the value of the dropdown, but I cannot set it back.
I have set the value using .val() method, but it is not working in this case.

Comment: Is the value you are setting one of the option in the dropdown?

Comment: @bitsmonkey Values which drop down has are 1 to 9. I want to set the default one  which blank. I even tried .val("") but still it does not work. I want to set the default value.

Comment: Can you briefly explain the expected outcome in the UI? your requirements seemed a bit weird.

Comment: Issue is when a user click on the back button on the browser, change event which is on change of drop down is not getting called. What i wanted to achieve was to make that drop down to default value so that it should impact other calculations. That is why his event to assign the default value to drop down. Other solution will be to call the change event when user click on the back button of the browser.

Comment: I am getting the value through if($(i)[0].value == "1"), then is it not possible to set the value if($(i)[0].value == "") like this?